# How to use Serilog with Elastik Search Sink and read from appsettings

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

we are curerntly using serilog and our logs are saving locally. We have an agent that then sends the logs to elastik. All our configurations are in appsettings.

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, configuration) => { configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration); });
```

We are now trying to send the logs directly to elastik. WIth this approach we are able to send logs directly to Elastik https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs-logging/dotnet/current/serilog-data-shipper.html

```
.WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new [] { new Uri("http://localhost:9200" )},
```

But we are hoping for a solution similiar to the original approach where we can still write to elastik search but it reads from configurations. May I ask if anyone has any suggestions on how to Write to ElastikSearch and all the configurations are within appsettings?